# ListView loading bitmap in viewholder raises memoryException

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I'm loading images in a viewholder that is used in a listview to reuse the layout of the rows. But after refreshing the list a couple of times i get a memory exception. Also, i load bitmaps in the size they are needed with the imageloader class, which has always worked correctly before so that's not the problem...

GetView method of the adapter:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        BaseBundelVO bundle = _bundles [position];
        string cellType = getCellType (bundle.Type);

        DSBundleListItem holder=null;
        View view = convertView;  


        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            if (cellType == "dsBundleCell") 
            {
                holder = new DSBundleListItem (_activity);
                view = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.dsBundleListItem, null);
                holder.IconIv = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.iconIv);
                holder.CoverIv = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.coverIv);
                holder.BundleProgress = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar> (Resource.Id.bundleProgress);

                view.Tag = holder;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (cellType == "dsBundleCell") 
            {
                holder = view.Tag as DSBundleListItem;
            }
        }

        holder.LoadImage (bundle.CoverImageLocation,bundle.Icon);

        return view;
    }
```

The GetImage method of the Viewholder (called by the loadimage method):

```
public async void GetImage(string originalImageLocation,string localImageLocation)
    {
        if (originalImageLocation == _iconImgLocation) 
        {
            IconIv.SetImageBitmap
            (
            Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap (await ImageLoader.DecodeSampledBitmapFromResourceAsync
            (localImageLocation,(int)ConvertDpToPix(30), (int)ConvertDpToPix(30)), (int)ConvertDpToPix(30), (int)ConvertDpToPix(30), true)
            );
        }

        if (originalImageLocation == _coverImgLocation) 
        {
            int screenWidth = _activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
            int imgWidth = screenWidth - (int)ConvertDpToPix (32f);
            int imgHeight = (int)(ConvertDpToPix(206f));

            BundleProgress.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

            CoverIv.SetImageBitmap 
            (
            Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap (await ImageLoader.DecodeSampledBitmapFromResourceAsync
            (localImageLocation, imgWidth, imgHeight), imgWidth, imgHeight, true)
            );
        }
    }
```

refreshing the adapter:

handler in the fragment that contains the listview:

```
void AllBundelsLoadedHandler (List<BaseBundelVO> bundels)
{
    list.OnRefreshCompleted ();
    adapter.SetData (bundels);
    adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
}
```

setdata method in the adapter:

```
public void SetData(List<BaseBundelVO> bundles)
    {
        _bundles = bundles;
    }
```

output:

```
[MonoDroid] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
[MonoDroid]     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:810)
[MonoDroid]     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:787)
[MonoDroid]     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:719)
[MonoDroid]     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:595)
[MonoDroid]     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at     mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
[MonoDroid]     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
[MonoDroid]     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you show the code where are you using this adapter? Probably you are creating it adapter multiple times instead of just refresh the list

Comment: We cannot help you if you post `snippets` like that. I meant show your `activity/fragment` where are you `initializing/using` the `adapter`. Otherwise as i said, check if you are creating it multiple times inside that `fragment/activity` instread of just refreshing it

Comment: I'm not creating it multiple times

Comment: I suggest you to use the industry leading library for such tasks, like Glide (recommended by Google), Picasso, Fresco or UIL. Just try for example the Glide if it will crash with the same problem. That way you will know for sure if its your ImageLoader issue or is it really something other like ViewHolder.

Comment: Can you show `extended logcat error `

Comment: Done. An external library is not an option btw, i'd like to know why i get the exception

Comment: Where are your images stored? I ran into an issue recently where I put xhdpi images in the drawables, and on xhdpi devices they were 2x and generating OOM errors.